# How to unlock local mercurial files?

Tags: linux, mercurial

I'm trying to remove a lock file and it won't work:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/My Book/montao$ sudo rm -f .hg/wlock
rm: cannot remove `.hg/wlock': Read-only file system
```

I neither can commit files with hg since it says hg is waiting for a lock. Can you recommend how to proceed? Here's the output from mount

```
$ mount
aufs on / type aufs (rw)
none on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
/dev/sr1 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/My Book type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=999,gid=999,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,flush)
```

Thank you

Comment: duplicate - [Mercurial stuck “waiting for lock”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock)

Comment: similar with difference that I can't even delete the repository file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible fix (albeit a kind of crappy one) might be:

```
$ mv .hg .hg-old
$ cp -r .hg-old .hg
```

Then see if you can remove the lock…

Comment: Thank you David. I get "Read Only File System" trying this: mv: cannot move `.hg' to `.hg-old': Read-only file system

Comment: Hrm, so is there any evidence that the filesystem is, actually, writeable? Have you tried unmounting/remounting?

Comment: It's a USB drive. Resetting it makes the filesystem writable and just after trying hg commit it goes into read-only. I'll try with a different computer to see if results are same.

Comment: I think the real question here is why the file system goes read-only, I think you should ask on Superuser about this. I seem to recall that this is an indication of a problem with the disk, that the OS puts the drive into read-only mode to avoid corrupting it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I cloned a new version and it seems ok now. I suspect there was a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Yea, +1 on asking on SuperUser. Running an fsck might not be a bad idea either.