# Can't push to mercurial (bitbucket) repo 'waiting for lock on repository'

Tags: mercurial

I'm currently getting this message whenever I try to push to one of our repositories:

`waiting for lock on repository <repo_path> held by '<hostname>:4228'`

The hostname is the PC I'm trying to push from, and the port number changes each time I try.

I've searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12865/324381) which suggests deleting the file .hg/store/lock but this file is not present on my computer.

Interestingly I see the lock file appear when I run the command, and see it removed again when I cancel the operation with ctrl-C.  It's almost like the hg process doesn't recognise that it is its own lock.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a stale file in the Bitbucket server.

Contact the support of the server and forward them the error message. Or just try again. Chances are that they have a cleanup process which removes stale locks after a timeout.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.  Don't you think it's strange that the port is changing with each attempt though? I mean, if it was a stale lock file, wouldn't the port number remain constant until that file was removed?

Comment: Same host? In that case, maybe someone has written a script which connects to the repo every 5 seconds...

Comment: @UpTheCreek: That port is the _client_ port. This is mostly random from the pool of free ports on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local `.hg` directory and delete the `wlock` file.