# Netbeans project file generation extremely slow (unusable)

Tags: java, netbeans, code-generation

I've been having issues with a Java project that I've been working on for a while.
Starting about 1 or 2 weeks ago, whenever I use Netbeans (8.0.2) to generate a new file in the project (right click on package > new file), the wizard will hang for up to 10 minutes before releasing control back to me. The file is created after about 5 minutes. This doesn't happen with any other project, only this one; but I can't find anything different in my project's configuration compared to projects that work.

I created a [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249842) about this on the Netbeans bug tracker, but it hasn't been looked at in over a week. It has a copy of the Netbeans output log, and a profiling snapshot of the class generation.

I've tried reinstalling Netbeans (remaining at 8.0.2), which didn't help, and I don't really know what else I can do to locate the problem. If anyone has experienced anything like this, or has any advice on how I can track down the issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7x5j5o776pqy4pq/AACmLEeJeEyGokddRtN5A0jba?dl=0) is a link to my project on Dropbox. Feel free to download a copy, compile it, run it, etc.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit, and I am using the official Netbeans 8.0.2 from netbeans.org, launched straight from the desktop (I am not using any particular command line arguments or enviroment variables, as far as I know)

Comment: it would be helpful to add more pertinent information, including operating system, whether you're using a distro release of NB or the official build from netbeans.org, any custom environmental settings (-Xmx, etc.)

Comment: Thanks - I have now added this information at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was that my Mercurial client was hanging when it made status calls, and Netbeans, due to a bug, was stuck waiting for it forever.

The issue with Mercurial can be worked around by deleting the [Mercurial log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock), and the bug with Netbeans was eventually fixed.