# How to remove hg lock in a git-hg repository?

Tags: git, mercurial, locking

When I run `git pull origin master` for the repository `hg::http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/corba/` (set as remote `origin`) hangs at

```
waiting for lock on repository /mnt/main/sources/jdk8u-jdk8u/.git/modules/corba/hg/origin/clone held by 'richter-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500-Touch\xef\x80\xa217970'
```

Interrupting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> displays the following trace

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/git-remote-hg", line 1322, in <module>

    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/bin/git-remote-hg", line 1286, in main
richter@richtercloud:/mnt/main/sources/jdk8u-jdk8u/corba$     repo = get_repo(url, alias)
  File "/usr/bin/git-remote-hg", line 433, in get_repo
    repo.pull(peer, heads=None, force=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1578, in pull
    return exchange.pull (self, remote, heads, force)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/exchange.py", line 559, in pull
    lock = pullop.repo.lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1098, in lock
    self.invalidate, _('repository %s') % self.origroot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1064, in _lock
    releasefn, desc=desc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.delay = self.lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 63, in lock
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

In a `hg` repository this can be resolved with solutions in [Mercurial stuck "waiting for lock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock), but in `git-hg` (doesn't have a `.hg` directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.hg` repository (normally under the source/checkout root) is available at `.git/hg/.hg/`. The lock can be removed from there following [Mercurial stuck "waiting for lock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock).

Answer (score 1):

Try to find your directory by running the following command -

`find / -name ".hg/store/"` -> `/` will start looking your directory from root folder. Run the command as `root` user to access all the folder.

Then follow the post [mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock)

Comment: Works. One seems to has access to the `hg` repository in `.git/hg/.hg/`. Searching under `/` doesn't make sense, though, searching under the source root is sufficient.

Comment: @KarlRichter I also know the searching under `/` doesn't make sense. It was for your sake of help that you don't miss the folder . And from your post it seems you forgot how to search through command line if you graphically can't find out. and after all you need to use the access of `root` If it works then accept the answer.

Comment: I just didn't think that there's might be a `.hg` directory at all. I'll accept the answer if improved. You can reuse the information in my first comment.

Comment: @KarlRichter that's the reason why the SO is. What you don't think, other can think and help each other and to extend the thoughts.

Comment: Searching in `/` is irrelevant for my question and doesn't help others because running `find` in source root always brings a better result than in `/`.

Comment: Fair enough. The "search idea"  is the another way to come out from your problem. Do you realize that !!!

Comment: No, I don't. I'm not contradicting the search idea, just proposing an optimization. Searching in `/` makes as much sense as searching on my friends PC or go to the library and search in a book. It is not wrong to search in `/` and a deterministic way to solve the problem in my question, but it's not a TIMTOWTDI case (which SO policy would encourage to be posted). It's just a non-optimal version of a legitimate answer.

Comment: You would not better and that's why before posting your question,you even didn't try to search to "your friends pc " or "going to library", even not in your own pc. Talking about optimization and deterministic first identify what you need and realize how to achieve.