# Lock prevents from pushing in local mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

Im trying to use mercurial for a project that will be developed on some disconnected PCs. I managed to setup the initial repo, and commit. But when I try to push, I get this message:

```
D:\work\havana2059-dvcs>hg push
pushing to D:\work\havana2059-dvcs
searching for changes
no changes found
waiting for lock on repository D:\work\havana2059-dvcs held by 'serenity:4816'
```

I have to interrupt it, because it simply stays there. How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial stuck "waiting for lock"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock)

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure it is supposed to be unlocked, then proceed to manually delete the lock file
see [Mercurial stuck "waiting for lock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock)

Comment: The lock file is created when I run hg push. It dissapears when I interrupt the process. So, seems that push cant recognize its own lock.

Comment: did you see comment regarding `.hg/wlock`?

Comment: also consider `hg debuglock` for troubleshooting

Comment: a weird symlink situation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock#25089553