# Mercurial HG on Tortoise stuck - waiting for lock on working directory

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Over night, my Tortoise stopped being able to **push** to my work repo, even though both my locks show **free**.

I get `waiting for lock on working directory of \\uGames/MyGameRepo held by process '24012' on host MyHost.`

After a long time of trying to push, I get `abort: working directory of \\uGames/MyGameRepo: timed out waiting for lock held by MyHost:24012.`

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865/mercurial-stuck-waiting-for-lock/12879#12879) on this, but **none** of the solutions there has resolved my problem.

Here is the output of my `hg debuglock`:

```
lock:  free
wlock: free
```

I cannot push anything... How can I fix this?

Comment: could you post the output of "hg debuglock"? What OS are you using? - Also when things like this happen for me, it's because there is a hg.exe process doing something, which I just have to find and kill.

Comment: @Tom I have added the output as an edit. The OS is Win10. I could see no hg process...

Comment: You may need to go to the repo on the server and check the lock files there?

Comment: That is a great idea. I will contact the server admin.

Comment: @StayOnTarget That was it! The server guy found a lock on the remote and freed it. I can push now. Thank you!

Comment: @CatarinaRuna glad that helped. We used to use the \\ network file share approach for hg as well. Switched to hg serve later (which I prefer). Its faster and generally seems to have fewer pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to go to the repo on the server and check the lock files there.

Since you are using a network file share as your repository, your local HG client will directly read/write files in that location. So it could be the lock files there that are the problem.